# Is there a Perl equivalent of Python's re.findall/re.finditer (iterative regex results)?

Tags: python, regex, perl, iterator

In Python compiled regex patterns [have a `findall` method](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) that does the following:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of
>   pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned
>   left-to-right, and matches are
>   returned in the order found. If one or
>   more groups are present in the
>   pattern, return a list of groups; this
>   will be a list of tuples if the
>   pattern has more than one group. Empty
>   matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of
>   another match.

What's the canonical way of doing this in Perl? A naive algorithm I can think of is along the lines of "while a search and replace with the empty string is successful, do [suite]". I'm hoping there's a nicer way. :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `/g` modifier in your match. From the `perlop` manual:

> The "`/g`" modifier specifies global pattern matching--that is, matching as many times as possible within the string.  How it behaves depends on the context.  In list context, it returns a list of the substrings matched by any capturing parentheses in the regular expression.  If there are no parentheses, it returns a list of all the matched strings, as if there were parentheses around the whole pattern.
>
> In scalar context, each execution of "`m//g`" finds the next match, returning true if it matches, and false if there is no further match.  The position after the last match can be read or set using the `pos()` function; see "`pos`" in `perlfunc`.   A failed match normally resets the search position to the beginning of the string, but you can avoid that by adding the "`/c`" modifier (e.g. "`m//gc`").  Modifying the target string also resets the search position.

Comment: D'oh -- of course! I should have realized this coming from Vim land.

Answer (score 8):

To build on Chris' response, it's probably most relevant to encase the `//g` regex in a `while` loop, like:

```
my @matches;
while ( 'foobarbaz' =~ m/([aeiou])/g )
{
    push @matches, $1;
}
```

Pasting some quick Python I/O:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'([aeiou])([nrs])','I had a sandwich for lunch')
[('a', 'n'), ('o', 'r'), ('u', 'n')]
```

To get something comparable in Perl, the construct could be something like:

```
my $matches = [];
while ( 'I had a sandwich for lunch' =~ m/([aeiou])([nrs])/g )
{
    push @$matches, [$1,$2];
}
```

But in general, whatever function you're iterating for, you can probably do within the `while` loop itself.

Comment: But what about `@matches = 'I had a sandwich for lunch' =~ m/([aeiou])([nrs])/g`? Sure, you get a flattened array, but then you can splice that off two apiece (in this case). :-)

Comment: Ah-hm. The beauty of Perl is there's always another way! I'm glad I said, "could be something like" :)

Answer (score 2):

Nice beginner reference with similar content to [@kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467800/is-there-a-perl-equivalent-of-pythons-re-findall-re-finditer-iterative-regex-re#467874)'s answer: [Perl Tutorial: Using regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl)