# Does a regular expression exist for enzymatic cleavage?

Tags: regex, perl, bioinformatics

Does a regular expression exist for (theoretical) [tryptic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tryptic) cleavage of [protein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein) sequences? The cleavage rule for trypsin is: after R or K, but not before P.

Example:

Cleavage of the sequence `VGTKCCTKPESERMPCTEDYLSLILNR` should result in these 3 sequences ([peptide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peptide)s):

```
 VGTK
 CCTKPESER
 MPCTEDYLSLILNR
```

Note that there is no cleavage after K in the second peptide (because P comes after K).

In Perl (it could just as well have been in C#, Python or Ruby):

```
  my $seq = 'VGTRCCTKPESERMPCTEDYLSLILNR';
  my @peptides = split /someRegularExpression/, $seq;
```

I have used this work-around (where a cut marker, =, is first inserted in the sequence and removed again if P is immediately after the cut maker):

```
  my $seq      = 'VGTRCCTKPESERMPCTEDYLSLILNR';
  $seq         =~ s/([RK])/$1=/g; #Main cut rule.
  $seq         =~ s/=P/P/g;       #The exception.
  my @peptides = split( /=/, $seq);
```

But this requires modification to a string that can potentially be very long and there can be millions of sequences. Is there a way where a regular expression can be used with split? If yes, what would the regular expression be?

---

Test platform: Windows XP 64 bit. ActivePerl 64 bit. From perl -v: v5.10.0 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread.

Comment: @unknown: Context... From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tryptic: "Trypsins are considered endopeptidases, i.e., the cleavage occurs within the polypeptide chain rather than at the terminal amino acids located at the ends of polypeptides."

Comment: Possibly the best SO question ever. How many others can boast code, science, and sexual inferences all at once, whilst at the same time being completely valid and answerable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You indeed need to use the combination of a positive lookbehind and a negative lookahead. The correct (Perl) syntax is as follows:

```
my @peptides = split(/(?!P)(?<=[RK])/, $seq);
```

Comment: Sure you mean negative lookahead and positive lookbehind.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to exclude that cases. Something like this should work:

```
split(/(?<=[RK](?!P))/, $seq)
```

Comment: Apologies if I am wrong, but wouldn't this end up splitting before the R/K in the sequence, rather than after?

Comment: Indeed, this won't work. The RK needs to be a positive lookbehind (?<=...)

Comment: @Anon and gab: yes, it results in cut before; 4 peptides: VGT, RCCTKPESE, RMPCTEDYLSLILN and R

Answer (score 4):

You can use lookaheads and lookbehinds to match this stuff while still getting the correct position.

```
/(?<=[RK])(?!P)/
```

*Should* end up splitting on a point after an R or K that is not followed by a P.

Comment: `/(?<[RK])(?=[^P])/` avoids splitting off an empty string at the end

Comment: For both: not accepted at compile time. For ysth's: "Sequence (?<[...) not recognized in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<[ <-- HERE RK])(?=[^P])/". I have updated the question with platform information.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the positive lookbehind syntax. It should be `(?<=...`. I'll correct it.

Comment: and I copied his error :( - it should be `/(?<=[RK])(?=[^P])/` - but since split by default removes trailing empty fields, it would only matter if you were splitting a fixed number of fields or using the regex with something other than split.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can use the `finditer` method to return non-overlapping pattern matches including start and span information. You can then store the string offsets instead of rebuilding the string.

Comment: perl can do this as well. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467800/is-there-a-perl-equivalent-of-pythons-re-findall-re-finditer-iterative-regex-re