# named captures that match more than once (Perl)

Tags: regex, perl

When I run this code:

```
$_='xaxbxc';
if(/(x(?<foo>.))+/) {
    say "&: ", $&;
    say "0: ", $-{foo}[0];
    say "1: ", $-{foo}[1];
 }
```

I get:

```
&: xaxbxc
0: c
1:
```

I understand that this is how it's supposed to work, but I would like to be able to somehow get the list of all matches `('a', 'b', 'c')` instead of just the last match (`c`).  How can I do this?

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459721/regex-group-in-perl-how-to-capture-elements-into-array-from-regex-group-that-mat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In situations like these, using embeded code blocks provides an easy way out:

```
my @match;
$_='xaxbxc';
if(/((?:x(.)(?{push @match, $^N}))+)/) {
    say "\$1: ", $1;
    say "@match"
}
```

which prints:

```
$1: xaxbxc
a b c
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using this as my solution... but the backtracking issue is tricky... I had to move my code block further away from the capture to make sure it didn't get called during the backtracking

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a way to do this in general (please correct me if I am wrong), but there is likely to be a way to accomplish the same end-goal in specific situations. For example, this would work for your specific code sample:

```
$_='xaxbxc';
while (/x(?<foo>.)/g) {
    say "foo: ", $+{foo};
}
```

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps we could find a solution for your actual problem even if there is no way to do repeating captures.

Answer (score 2):

Perl allows a regular expression to match multiple times with the "g" switch past the end. Each individual match can then be looped over, as described in the Global Matching subsection of the [Using Regular Expressions in Perl section of the Perl Regex Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl):

```
while(/(x(?<foo>.))+/g){
    say "&: ", $&;
    say "foo: ", $+{foo};
}
```

This will produce an iterated list:

```
&: xa
foo: a
&: xb
foo: b
&: xc
foo: c
```

Which still isn't what you want, but it's really close. Combining a global regex (/g) with you previous local regex probably will do it. Generally, make a capturing group around your repeated group, then re-parse just that group with a global regex that represents just a single iteration of that group, and iterate over it or use it as a list.

It looks like a question fairly similar to this one- at least in answer, if not forumlation- has been answered by someone much more competent at Perl than I: ["Is there a Perl equivalent of Python's re.findall/re.finditer (iterative regex results)?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467800/is-there-a-perl-equivalent-of-pythons-re-findall-re-finditer-iterative-regex-re) You might want to check the answers for that as well, with more details about the proper use of global regexes. (Perl isn't my language, I just have an unhealthy appreciation for regular expressions.)

Answer (score 1):

The `%-` variable is used when you have more than one of the same named group in the same pattern, not when the a given group happens to be iterated.

That’s why `/(.)+/` doesn’t load up `$1` with each separate character, just with the last one. Same with `/(<x>.)+/`. However, with `/(<x>.)(<x>.)/` you have two different `<x>` groups, so `$-{x}`.  Consider:

```
% perl -le '"foobar" =~ /(?<x>.)(?<x>.)/; print "x#1 is $-{x}[0], x#2 is $-{x}[1]"'
x#1 is f, x#2 is o

% perl -le '"foobar" =~ /(?:(?<x>.)(?<x>.))+/; print "x#1 is $-{x}[0], x#2 is $-{x}[1]"'
x#1 is a, x#2 is r
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that is exactly what you're looking for, but the following code should do the trick.

```
$_='xaxbxc';
@l = /x(?<foo>.)/g;

print join(", ", @l)."\n";
```

But, I'm not sure this would work with overlapping strings.